# How to optimize the following function

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm having a bottleneck issue with the following function. Takes too long to process the list of lists. The list that I am about to detail, has millions of lists (could hold up to almost 40M lists).

The function iterates over the list of lists and for every list where its 10th element contains a -1, gets its index position. Then checks if for the same index position of the -1, in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements of the list the same index position has value 0, if so that list most be deleted.

Let us see an example with just one list:

```
list_item = [[0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]]
```

As we can see, the 10th element (I'm considering the very first list item as 0), [-1, 0, 0], -1 is in index position 0. Items 1st, 2nd and 3rd ([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]) have 0 for the same index position as -1, hence the whole list must be deleted fro the list.

```
import copy    

def filter_vnf_departures(states):
    """ Filters out states where the VNF departure can not occur """
    temp = states.copy()
    for state in states:
        vnf_index = [i for i, e in enumerate(state[10]) if e == -1]
        if -1 in state[10]:
             ec1 = state[1][vnf_index[0]]
             ec2 = state[2][vnf_index[0]]
             cdc = state[3][vnf_index[0]]
             if ec1 == 0 and ec2 == 0 and cdc == 0:
                temp.remove(state)

    return temp
```

Let me, as an example, detail an input list to the function. For obvious reasons, this list is very small compared to the ones that I have to deal.

```
input_list = [[[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```

And this is the out put list that the function must return:

```
output_list = [[[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```

Can the function be optimized so it processes everything faster?

Comment: What are the possible values for the list elements [1, 0,-1]?

Comment: Within the list? Or for the 10th element of the list?

Comment: state[10] mostly

Comment: only one of its elements can be either 1 or -1 in state[10]. So basiccally, the options for state[10] are:  [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1]]

Comment: In that case, why do you still check the sum when you already have found -1? Could the sum be any different than -1?

Comment: I might tag this with "numpy" and un-accept my answer. My gut tells me that a numpy wizard will be able to come up with something even faster. If my answer is fastest after a day then feel free to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be faster when I try via `timeit`:

```py
def filter_vnf_departures2a(states):
    for state in states:
        if sum(state[10]) != -1:
            yield state
            continue

        vnf_index = state[10].index(-1)
        if state[1][vnf_index] or state[2][vnf_index] or state[3][vnf_index]:
            yield state
```

Though I personally like this second alternative. It seems faster than the original, but slower than the first alternative above.

```py
def filter_vnf_departures2b(states):
    for state in states:
        vnf_index = next((i for i,v in enumerate(state[10]) if v == -1), None)
        if vnf_index is None or state[1][vnf_index] or state[2][vnf_index] or state[3][vnf_index]:
            yield state
```

Given:

```py
input_list = [[[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
output_list = [[[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]

def filter_vnf_departures(states):
    temp = copy.copy(states)
    for state in states:
        vnf_index = [i for i, e in enumerate(state[10]) if e == -1]
        if sum(state[10]) == -1:
             ec1 = state[1][vnf_index[0]]
             ec2 = state[2][vnf_index[0]]
             cdc = state[3][vnf_index[0]]
             if ec1 == 0 and ec2 == 0 and cdc == 0:
                temp.remove(state)
    return temp
```

Then I get:

```
print(filter_vnf_departures(input_list) == list(filter_vnf_departures2a(input_list)))
print(filter_vnf_departures(input_list) == list(filter_vnf_departures2b(input_list)))
```

as:

```
True
True
```

Comment: Your first version is by far fastest than mine, it still faster than your second version, although your second version is more elegant. Thx.

Comment: @krm76 I made a slight modification to the first faster alternative that makes it faster still. Turns out my use of `any()` was slowing things down.

Answer (score -1):

Returning a filtered version of the list as opposed to a full copy with elements removed should be faster.

Something like:

```
return [s for s in states if keep(s)]
```

where `keep` is a function that returns `True` is state `s` is to be kept and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Can you elaborate more your answer?